# How to save recent project showing in JetBrains (open recent) and save (project name and project path) as text file or findout where it occupy?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

[image]

I would like to clean install Windows so my IntelliJ product and other software will be lost. I want to find out my recent project and save that project into an external drive.

Here is this picture. What I did? Open Recent and click the project then find the location. My computer is very slow while opening each project I have around 50 projects here.

Is there any way to find out where the recent projects are saved so I could access that programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

You can check the `options/recentProjects.xml` file in the [Configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory).

Sample location for IntelliJ IDEA on Windows:

```
c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3\options\recentProjects.xml
```

For Android Studio:

```
c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2021.1\options\recentProjects.xml
```

Look for these tags to find the location of your projects:

```
<entry key="<file path>">
```

Comment: thanks .it works except android studio.

Comment: Your question was tagged as #intellij-idea, so I provided the answer for IntelliJ IDEA. For Android Studio only the IDE name in the path would be different.

Comment: ok. it is useful .your answer perfect and it worked  .i am looking other product too..do you have any suggestion in android studio ?.

Comment: Not sure I understand what suggestion you are looking for.

Comment: i coud'nt find android studio option folder and recentprojects.xml file.

Comment: See the updated answer.