# from where vscode recent project list showing .is it from xml file or registry or db?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I would like to clean install windows. so my Visualstudio code  product and other software will be lost. So I want to find out my recent project and save that project into an external drive. Here is this picture. what I did?.  open recent and click the project then find the location. my computer is very slow while opening each project I have more than 50 projects recent.is there any way to find out where the recent saved?.

[Similar in jetbrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515402/how-to-save-recent-project-showing-in-jetbrains-open-recent-and-save-project)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11 you can find recent opened files for Visual Studio Code under

**%APPDATA%\Code\User\workspaceStorage<number>**

I think in Windows 10 is the same.
There, You'll find a file called state.vscdb (a SQLite db) and state.vscdb.backup (a backup copy of state.vscdb).
You can open it with a portable version of SQLite DB Browser.
I use the one of https://sqlitebrowser.org/, section download.
You'll find version for Win, MacOS, Linux ecc...
Open the program, then under FILE --> Open Database in only reading mode, find the above mentioned path, show all files (Non only Database file SQLite).
Once open, second tab (Browse data, I think, 'cause I use a localized version of the program and I don't know if in English is so call the second tab).
Under the first column (key) find "history.entries" (form me the 4th row) and in the second column (value), You can read all your file history entries.
Have a good Epifany day.

Comment: i coud'nt find such folder in ,appdata and user directory

Comment: Which version of SysOp do You use?

Comment: windows10 os using